# sound problem (the left speaker doesn't working)

Tags: 14.04, sound, multimedia

I have a problem with the speakers hardware and the left speaker doesn't working... how can i make the whole sound be in the right speaker? some videos have sound just in the left speaker so changing the balance 100% to the right doesn't helping me... in windows 8.1 I solved the problem by activating Headphone Virtualization.

(i"m using headphones)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved by changing output from stereo to mono. 
Take a look at [This](https://superuser.com/questions/657876/mono-sound-output-in-ubuntu) question on Superuser.